# Como faço para saber se o usuário realmente deseja voltar, quando clica no botão voltar do celular?

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma `activity` que guarda determinados dados, e quando o usuário aperta o botão de voltar (Botão de Hardware do Avd, por exemplo), a aplicação não volte para a Tela anterior, mas sim que abra uma tela de diálogo questionando se o usuário deseja retornar à tela anterior sabendo que perderá os dados salvos.

Como fazer a captura desse evento?

Comment: O título da sua pergunta é diferente do corpo da pergunta. No primeiro você está perguntando sobre UX, e  no segundo sobre programação.

Comment: Apenas comentando que isso não é uma prática recomendada na plataforma Android. O botão voltar deve SEMPRE voltar imediatamente. Salve os dados em algum estado se preciso, ou simplesmente deixe o usuário perder os dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimente usar esse código:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//Handle the back button
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    //Ask the user if they want to quit
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setTitle(R.string.quit)
    .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //Stop the activity
            YourClass.this.finish();    
        }

    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
    .show();

    return true;
}
else {
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

Ou esse para Android 2.0+

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setTitle("Closing Activity")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();    
    }

})
.setNegativeButton("No", null)
.show();
}
```

Comment: Eu nem consideraria a primeira opção. Apps abaixo de 2.2 nem sequer tem acesso a play store.

Comment: Mas ainda podem instalar APK's por transferência.

Comment: Sim, mas se alguém tiver um aparelho rodando Eclair, vende pro museu que dá uma grana :)

Comment: JP funcionou perfeitamente a segunda forma, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Um pouco de Google me deu o seguinte resultado:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
return true;

}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Ele apenas checa se o keyevent é igual ao keycode dado!
Lembrando que se você formatar um pouco, você pode usar o código para detectar qualquer keypress!

(fonte: http://nisha113a5.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/intercept-home-key-android.html)